# How to add an image to a JFrame title bar?

Tags: java, image, swing, icons, jframe

I want to add an image (small icon) to the `javax.swing.JFrame` title bar.

How can I do it?

Comment: `JPanel` doesn't have a title bar...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since `JPanel` doesn't have a title bar, I'm assuming that you're referring to `JFrame`. That being said, use [`setIconImage(...)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setIconImage%28java.awt.Image%29).

---

Here is an example of using `setIconImages()`.

```
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.*;

class FrameIcons {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url16 = new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0KKu.png");
        URL url32 = new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVVMb.png");

        final List<Image> icons = new ArrayList<Image>();
        icons.add(ImageIO.read(url16));
        icons.add(ImageIO.read(url32));

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame("Frame Icons");
                f.setIconImages(icons);
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                f.setSize(200,100);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### Frame using 16x16 icon

[image]

### Application tabbing using the 32x32 icon

[image]

Comment: ..see also related method `setIconImages()` (note the plural form).  If you set images of size 16x16 & 32x32, the 1st will be used as the frame icon (on systems that support it - I noted recently that the Mac. does not), & the second displayed when 'alt tabbing' between different applications.  I have no idea which other platforms besides Windows display an icon to represent apps. when changing between them.

Comment: @mre:  I could not resist adding an example using a couple of images borrowed from another thread about these parts.  I figured it was best to add it as an edit to your question, since it is effectively the same answer.  If you prefer, edit it out & I'll add it as a separate answer.

Comment: @Andrew, this is perfect. I appreciate the detailed elaboration you provided...it definitely enriches the value of this answer. kudos to you! :)

Comment: @mre:  A nice adjunct to (what I believe is) the 'answer to the *right* question'.  ;)

Comment: @mre: thanks for the details well structured ans.. With your help i found that the thing suitable for me is the Inner Frames. Thanks again for your great answer...