# Java app has fuzzy icon in the alt-tab list in GNU/Linux Mint

Tags: java, linux, gnu, gnome-3, linux-mint

I'm using JFrame.setIconImages to set the icons for a JFrame in my application, working from the example at [How to add an image to a JFrame title bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403821/how-to-add-an-image-to-a-jframe-title-bar).

On Mint (Cinnamon desktop), I'm getting a fuzzy icon in the alt-tab list. The first icon in the list passed to setIconImages is 32X32px and the second is 96x96px. It looks like the 32x32 image is just getting scaled up. I've tried it with one high-resolution image using both setIconImage and setIconImages, and with two high-resolution images, to no avail.

This is really bugging me because most of the other icons in Mint look so nice.

Does anyone know if there is a way to fix this, or is it a Cinnamon/Gnome-3 issue? I just installed a Java app from the repository, and it seems to have the same problem.

--edit-- Just tried it in Debian Squeeze. It behaves the same way, but the alt-tab list has smaller icons, so it isn't noticeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
<sub>(source: [speedduck.net](http://speedduck.net/images/share/gnome-3-alt-tab-icons.jpg))</sub>

I installed the application on Debian Wheezy, Gnome 3. The icon on the right-hand side of the image is the installed application (icons in /usr/share/icons/hicolor... and launched via jarwrapper). The icon on the left-hand side is is the application running as an executable .jar file. In both cases setIconImages is being called with 32x32 and 96x96 icons.

Apparently, loading multiple icons doesn't make any difference, they just get scaled down anyway. What works is to install the application so the system can find its icons. I suspect my problem with Mint is that it is looking for icons in a different subdirectory of /usr/share/icons.