# How to change default program icon?

Tags: java, eclipse, icons

```
ImageIcon programIcon = new ImageIcon("/images/icon.png");
userRatingsPanel.setIconImage(programIcon.getImage());
```

That's my current code (and jframe too obv)

I'm trying to change the default icon

[image]

thanks!

Comment: Use [`JFrame#setIconImages`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setIconImages-java.util.List-) instead - as demonstrated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403821/how-to-add-an-image-to-a-jframe-title-bar/6403846#6403846)

Comment: huhhh so do i need to make a new method for it?

Comment: No, the mean already exists, but it tasks a list of images which allows the OS to pick the best one to use in a number of different situations, rather than having to up/down scale a single icon (I'd also make sure that the image is actually been loaded)

Comment: Sorry, im really new to Java. This is actually for a project I have to do for school. I have the icon image stored in a "images" folder. It's named icon.png

Comment: What I mean is that I wanna make THAT icon show up in the windows taskbar and in the top left of the program

Comment: Try adding something like `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, programIcon);` after you've loaded the image, see if the image is displayed in the resulting dialog, if it is, then it's been loaded correctly, if not, you have another issue to resolve

Comment: Huh? :O It's currently like this http://i.imgur.com/sNACRr2.png

Comment: Nono I want http://i.imgur.com/pdpTxow.png and http://i.imgur.com/nV5LRvT.png replaced by the icon :)

Comment: Okay, sorry, running about termanology :P - Use `setIconImages` can support that functionality, but you may need to supply multiple images at different size, take a look at the [**example I linked earlier**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html)

Comment: Uhh i dont want it in the system traayyyyy :P I want it as the icon (top left of the window and the general icon in the bottom (instead of coffee one)

Comment: Yes - two things. 1- Make sure that the original image is been loaded; 2- use `setIconImages` instead of `setIconImage` - see [**linked example**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403821/how-to-add-an-image-to-a-jframe-title-bar/6403846#6403846) (I sware my copy/paste functionality isn't working :P)

Comment: Ok I got it... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You Can change your Icon

```
setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(YourFrame.class.getResource("Your Source")));
```